# Get source branch in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have an artifact generated only in a pull request, and I am looking to then use that source branch name in my `main` branch on a PR merge.

```
- name: Download artifact
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
  with:
    workflow: apply.yml
    name: artifact
    branch: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.default_branch }}'
```

The syntax for `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.default_branch`  is null, however.

Is there any way to pull the PR branch name?

Comment: What payload you have in the event depends on how the workflow is triggered. On what events are you triggering your workflow?

Comment: @rethab The event I am looking for is a PR merge into master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this question online, here's how I solved it:

```
- uses: tonynguyenit18/github-action-custom-vars@v1

- name: "merge branch"
  id: merge_branch
  run: echo "::set-output name=merge_branch::$RECENT_MERGED_BRANCH_NAME"
```

This sets the merged branch in a variable which you can call by using: `${{ steps.merge_branch.outputs.merge_branch }}`